# Download video link

Tags: html, download

I want to create the download link for this video. Kindly Guide me how can i do it. I want the browser to take automatically the download link and start downloading the file when someone clicks on Download This Video

My Try

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<a href="1.mp4" target="_blank">Download This video</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) is what you are looking for...

Comment: thumbs up. Found what i was lookinf for

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<a href="1.mp4" target="_blank" download>Download This video</a>
```

HTML 5 has this awsome attribute..